# How to bundle multiple AARs to maven

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I have two AARs that I want to package them into one library and upload to maven. The two AARs are ***depending on each other.***
The structure of the library is as follows:

```
LibraryA
--- AAR1
--- AAR2
```

The dependecies in build.gradle of LibraryA is

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':AAR1')
   compile project(':AAR2')
}
```

But when I am using LibraryA in a new project. I got error that it couldnt find AAR1 and AAR2
The error message is like:

```
Failed to resolve: AAR1 
Failed to resolve: AAR2
```

If, I am using transitive=true

```
compile ('com.example.LibraryA:1.0.0@aar') {
   transitive=true
 }
```

The error is it couldnt find aatr or theme resources in AAR1 and AAR2.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated

EDIT:

settings.gradle of LibraryA

```
include ':app', 'AAR1', 'AAR2'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gradle - Cannot find sub module for maven library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013042/gradle-cannot-find-sub-module-for-maven-library)

Comment: Like in your other question, i think the problem is with your `settings.gradle`

Comment: @chenrui, updated the question, i dont think its settings.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibraryA is in your maven repository, are AAR1 and AAR2 also in maven repository?
1. publish AAR1 and AAR2 into maven
2. republish LibraryA into maven with dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.example.AAR1:1.0.0'
  compile 'com.example.AAR2:1.0.0'
}
```

if you do not want to do this, maybe you need to make a fat-aar with https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar